# Is there a way to access a logged in users saved posts?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

When you like something you have that ability to save it. I'm wondering if you could access your saved posts through the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not available at this time.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference